# apply function with external conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, apply

I have a dataframe `df` with random values

```
df <- data.frame(x1=runif(20,1,200),x2=runif(20,1,18),x3=runif(20,1,7),x4=runif(20,1,3),x5=runif(20,1,25),x6=runif(20,1,220),x7=runif(20,1,10),x8=runif(20,1,8),x9=runif(20,1,20),x10=runif(20,1,32))
df

           x1        x2       x3       x4        x5         x6       x7       x8        x9       x10
1   43.942462 14.983885 4.267664 2.591210 19.650770  95.710478 8.830253 7.089017  5.341859  3.574852
2  185.965077  8.099796 3.592361 1.953196  8.837645 111.846707 8.180938 3.355258 13.889081 26.878697
3   83.532083  2.782204 3.160955 1.892041 23.216698  80.521986 3.864614 6.799805 17.493065  9.246177
4   48.416861 17.019713 5.182366 2.501890  8.108828 219.419766 4.687034 6.785789  2.525997  7.145447
5   66.766778 11.716819 1.649946 2.136352  2.957554 126.164722 9.980739 1.919323 16.556541  5.447096
6   78.305312 12.148354 6.408544 2.644811 10.362618  53.112153 1.092853 1.360766  6.693875 17.108564
7   64.995759 13.385556 3.375907 1.923173 19.732286 219.780082 4.074889 4.609356  7.098822 25.412262
8  196.463100 17.491693 2.317492 2.573539 24.350820  36.696244 6.277854 6.247473  5.535765 12.121822
9   48.467431 11.659182 4.324854 1.380067 15.269617 102.453557 2.724937 1.481521 14.916894  3.451188
10 134.913063  8.927522 2.637946 1.526043 17.956797  49.671752 5.014152 4.737910  4.241197 28.916885
11 190.841615  2.639374 5.038702 2.806088 15.127840   8.841983 2.155842 7.589245 13.799412 28.025792
12  46.963826 11.212431 4.944327 2.937039 16.410549  25.048928 6.330826 5.006221  2.986566 17.005088
13  97.258821 17.847892 6.202023 2.228292 19.804482 159.922462 2.587568 4.175234  5.360039 15.812061
14 123.439971 15.415940 5.785273 2.075161 11.496406  12.449913 6.484951 7.911373 11.578242 22.398292
15   4.225315 11.775122 6.908108 2.980960 22.768381 109.853774 2.535843 7.293656 13.290552 29.302949
16  49.927327  4.086780 3.941200 1.129892 18.200466 164.281496 6.881178 6.199219  4.091858 29.963647
17 105.716881 12.421335 6.527660 2.767754 22.055987 208.188895 8.125112 7.702927  3.027778 20.080756
18 195.205248  5.749007 6.204989 1.815563  3.875226 200.608675 1.500572 7.116924  1.608354 13.292293
19  27.564433 16.788191 1.648707 2.360290 22.539064 192.914543 1.327605 6.096303  7.105979 22.650040
20 122.620812 11.475314 5.588179 1.884028  3.692936 200.056348 3.248232 1.562624 18.998767 29.424066
```

and a vector `ind` with certain values corresponding to each column in `df`. The values in `ind` are an indicator for a normalisation procedure.

```
ind
x1     x2     x3     x4     x5     x6     x7     x8     x9    x10 
0.800  1.000  0.400  0.010  6.000  0.100  0.180  0.006 10.000  1.000
```

Now I need to write a code that applies a desired function to each value in a column in `df` if its corresponding value in `ind` is equal to or above a certain threshold value.

For an example, if this threshold would be 0.8, the affected columns in `df` would be `x1`, `x2`, `x5`, `x9`, and `x10`.

I have tried something like `apply(df,2,function(x)...` but I'm not skilful enough to insert the `ifelse` that is clearly needed.

Comment: Try `lapply(df[ind >= thresh], myfun)`

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(df[,ind>=threshold],2,function(x) {...
```

should do the job.

Comment: It's fine. But don't use `apply` over margin 2 for data.frames

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Can you clarify why one shouldn't use `apply` over margin 2 for data.frames?

Comment: @OlliJ, because that will convert your data to `matrix`. It's usually better to use `lapply` instead.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just subset the dataframe to select the columns that fits in your threshold criteria `df[,ind >= threshold]`

```
> df <- data.frame(x1=runif(20,1,200),x2=runif(20,1,18),x3=runif(20,1,7),
+                  x4=runif(20,1,3),x5=runif(20,1,25),x6=runif(20,1,220),
+                  x7=runif(20,1,10),x8=runif(20,1,8),x9=runif(20,1,20),
+                  x10=runif(20,1,32))
> df
           x1        x2       x3       x4        x5        x6       x7       x8        x9       x10
1  144.616823  5.066181 6.577798 1.941608 19.250274  79.88517 3.487795 5.397938 19.226113  9.469675
2  143.563809  1.608130 6.446411 2.071802 12.636476 193.12108 5.685940 1.643825 11.111157  5.676330
3  124.396884  3.693522 3.660122 1.346020 21.605446  98.05443 1.965067 5.332797  7.879099  2.252806
4   75.936173  9.596695 1.130494 2.014904 19.460231 195.26396 1.132060 6.338672  4.077532 31.391598
5    8.913065  1.170144 3.197571 1.011599  3.970510 211.02147 6.483770 5.654871 12.669959 16.107771
6  177.159043 11.625298 6.282233 1.576242 13.997114 119.77652 9.507075 4.430359 13.564249  1.256496
7   70.383858 14.545778 2.018208 2.990232  3.391777  83.47019 2.232830 7.433207  1.809452 18.440641
8   48.883343  8.747942 4.473287 1.163179 13.949834  77.34972 3.959059 1.320038 10.385028  2.291721
9   85.618694  5.421825 4.675017 1.935956 10.877031 185.46998 7.548788 4.160425 16.304787 23.373557
10 152.615778 12.088414 2.154604 2.266516 20.823971 159.11784 7.047805 3.570086 18.286411 22.731629
11  83.139696  1.909547 3.124565 2.580109  4.726824 100.42819 1.994356 2.910579  2.034623 26.973796
12  85.488980  4.193826 2.051200 1.063903 18.012469 210.97311 5.783519 5.846847  9.931950 17.261856
13 172.446057 14.226508 3.080864 2.153755  6.844384 201.36755 1.593935 4.389736 10.549154 12.728925
14  23.892525 13.907691 2.494084 1.658334 11.922202 159.96523 1.605302 4.113502  7.151511 11.186883
15  24.836826 16.390015 2.989483 2.327674 17.067639  44.66071 5.275591 2.970786  6.068440  1.898431
16  84.552408  6.670091 3.059626 1.693665  6.243420 175.88141 9.638818 2.090328 17.085817 23.759445
17  29.615649 12.239127 5.728309 1.034658  3.793404  17.34458 2.211930 7.648141 13.080505 21.024933
18 106.492512 13.543715 3.244059 2.167515 21.803114 204.25419 7.807202 1.519835  1.117334  9.732187
19 156.503788 16.186274 4.825950 2.019083  6.594384  61.66293 9.693650 5.181686 10.884431 23.105221
20 196.592843  6.461601 4.183722 1.742368 21.129107 175.12238 9.239206 6.657412  8.371315 15.648119
> ind <- c(0.800, 1.000, 0.400, 0.010, 6.000, 0.100, 0.180,  0.006, 10.000, 1.000)
> ind
 [1]  0.800  1.000  0.400  0.010  6.000  0.100  0.180  0.006 10.000  1.000
> sapply(df[,ind>=0.8], function(x){max(x)})
       x1        x2        x5        x9       x10 
196.59284  16.39002  21.80311  19.22611  31.39160
```

[Edited to avoid use of apply over dimension 2]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could apply such an approach:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=runif(20,1,200),x2=runif(20,1,18),x3=runif(20,1,7),x4=runif(20,1,3),x5=runif(20,1,25),x6=runif(20,1,220),x7=runif(20,1,10),x8=runif(20,1,8),x9=runif(20,1,20),x10=runif(20,1,32))
ind <- c(0.8,1.0,0.4,0.01,6.0,0.1,0.18, 0.006, 10.0,  1.0)
threshold <- 0.8

m<- ind>=0.8
index<- m %in% c(TRUE)
df2<-df[,index]
df3<-apply(df,2,scale)
```

The function to normalize you can choose on your own.